# Load BitmapImage in background thread causes UI thread to stutter

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml

I have a bit of code which loads a BitmapImage in the background, freezes it, and sends it off to the UI thread. However, even without sending to the UI thread, the act of loading a JPG into a BitmapImage causes the UI to stutter, even though it's happening on a background thread.

On reading about BitmapImage, it seems it might be the case that even if in a background thread, BitmapImage will use the Dispatcher and therefore run at least part of it's loading process in the UI thread.

This is pretty bad news for my animation capability, as it stutters and stalls on loading images in the background. As far as my code is concerned, the only bit to run in the UI thread is setting the 'Source' property on an Image to be the BitmapImage.

So, simple question, how can I load up a JPG into a BitmapImage without touching the UI thread?

```
BitmapImage bi = null;

bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.UriSource = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute);
bi.DecodePixelWidth = 250;
bi.EndInit();

bi.Freeze();

(recv as UIElement).Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine(path + " GOT IMAGE FROM IMAGE");
    recv.recieveBitmap(bi);
}), DispatcherPriority.Input);

Action a = () => processImage(p);
Task t = new Task(a);

_jobs.Add(t);

t.Start();
```

Comment: Can we see what you have tried?

Comment: OK, I've put some code into the original post, everything apart from inside the 'Invoke' is within a background thread, running as a Task.

Comment: Do you fire these Tasks off every frame? Can you include some code about the loop?

Comment: Also, note that a Task is not necessarily run on another thread. How are you kicking off the task?

Comment: Not every frame, basically, a Timer runs and tells my app to update about 30 times a second, on the first update, images are loaded, and they fall down the screen in an animation, when they drop off the bottom of the screen, the images are replaced with new ones. On loading of the new ones, that's when I get my UI stuttering, if I simple move the images back to the top of the screen, the whole thing runs smoothly. I'll edit the original to show how I launch the Task.

Answer (score 1):

A probably more efficient way to load a BitmapImage in a background thread would be to load it from a FileStream, instead of setting its `UriSource` property.

```
var bi = new BitmapImage();

using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.DecodePixelWidth = 250;
    bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bi.StreamSource = stream;
    bi.EndInit();
}

bi.Freeze();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, just tried it, does not seem to make any difference that I can tell.